# Stoping incomming mail for an Exchange Mail box

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003

I have an disabled Windows 2003 SBS user.

I would like so save the users mail box but stop it from receiving mail.

If I can't do that I would like to export the mail box and delete the user.

What is the simplest way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to change their SMTP address to something arbitrary.  They will still exist and the mailbox would still be accessible, but mail to the previous address(es) will start bouncing.

In an active directory environment, this would mean opening Active Directory Users and Computers, right-clicking their account, choosing the "E-mail Addresses" tab, then modifying the list entries that match the type "SMTP."

Answer (score 3):

Set a delivery restriction to the user itself. I don't have an Exchange 2003 system any more so I can't guide you to the steps, but this is what we did to 'fully disable' a mailbox. Once you set the delivery restriction, mail sent to that user gets bounced with an, "access denied," error.

By default everyone gets the ability to accept messages "From Everyone". What we did was to set that to, "only from:" an added themselves to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the user properties and go to Exchange General> Delivery Restrictions, here you can select to only accept messages from authenticated users, this means you won't get emails from outside but only domain users.

Answer (score 0):

Change the password and place a quota on it that is below the total size. 
It will stop mail for that user and allow you to continue accessing the mailbox via sharing in exchange if you add yourself to the permission list. Re-enable the user if you want to access the mailbox via outlook web access or outlook. Also, you can remove the address e-mail address from the mailbox via user and computers under active directory.

Use exmerge to export the mail or use outlook to export the mail to a pst file.